# Better option to create workflows .net or Workflow-foundation?

Tags: asp.net, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have just got a project from one of the automobile company in which i have to create a workflow application.Requirement is that we have to create a web based system to plan and track a automobile accessory development workflow  throughout the process life cycle.Let me elaborate a bit more like the client automobile company creates accessories for vehicles.So my workflow starts from design of accessory,acceptance and approval of accessory,development of accessory,sales of accessory and profits due to that particular accessory.

Now my problem is that i am not sure about whether to use WWF or not,Since i don't have prior experience of Workflow-foundation,Can somebody guide/suggest me what to use asp.net/c# or Workflow-foundation-4(i can learn if there are specific advantages since i have enough time to develop this project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years ago I developed an application which contains a workflow. We started out with WWF but quite quickly abandoned it in favour of our own state implementation on the entity objets intead.

WWF has a great designer and is simple to get started with. Unfortunately it is very much of a black box. The one feature that made us abandon it was that if persisting the state of a long running workflow, we found no simple way to query for the current state to be able to show it with other information.